# How to display Webservice list (Apache CXF)

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws

I am trying to display the Service list served by a simple jax-ws service using CXF.

Using these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this class:

```
@WebService
public class Foo {

    @WebMethod
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

I can publish the service with this line:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:1234/foo", new Foo());
```

Then I can display the wsdl browsing to the url: `http://127.0.0.1:1234/foo?wsdl`

But I don't find any way to obtain the service list html page. I tried the /services url ( from [cxf](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) *By default, Apache CXF creates a /services page containing a listing of the available endpoints* ), but nothing. Is there a way to enable it ?
Can it be done programmatically (not using xml file) ?